# Tensorflow: How to identify input variable? / Is it possible to save and use predict without input placeholder?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Using Tensorflow 1.3.1

I have created a neural network and trained it and now I would like to save it using `tf.saved_model.simple_save(sess, export_dir, inputs, outputs)` so that I can use it to make predictions. Therefore I need to find the 'inputs' variable of my model.

The model I have is defined like this:

```
def __call__(self, obs, reuse=False):
    with tf.variable_scope(self.name) as scope:
        if reuse:
            scope.reuse_variables()

        x = obs
        x = tf.layers.dense(x, self.nb_units)
        if self.layer_norm:
            x = tc.layers.layer_norm(x, center=True, scale=True)
        x = tf.nn.relu(x)

        x = tf.layers.dense(x, self.nb_units)
        if self.layer_norm:
            x = tc.layers.layer_norm(x, center=True, scale=True)
        x = tf.nn.relu(x)

        x = tf.layers.dense(x, self.nb_actions,
                            kernel_initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer(minval=-3e-3, maxval=3e-3))
        x = tf.nn.tanh(x)
    return x
```

When I look at the variables in the scope (using):

```
for i in tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope='actor'):
    print(i.name + ':\t', end=''); print(i)
```

I get:

```
actor/dense/kernel:0:   <tf.Variable 'actor/dense/kernel:0' shape=(270, 512) dtype=float32_ref>
actor/dense/bias:0: <tf.Variable 'actor/dense/bias:0' shape=(512,) dtype=float32_ref>
actor/LayerNorm/beta:0: <tf.Variable 'actor/LayerNorm/beta:0' shape=(512,) dtype=float32_ref>
actor/LayerNorm/gamma:0:    <tf.Variable 'actor/LayerNorm/gamma:0' shape=(512,) dtype=float32_ref>
actor/dense_1/kernel:0: <tf.Variable 'actor/dense_1/kernel:0' shape=(512, 512) dtype=float32_ref>
actor/dense_1/bias:0:   <tf.Variable 'actor/dense_1/bias:0' shape=(512,) dtype=float32_ref>
actor/LayerNorm_1/beta:0:   <tf.Variable 'actor/LayerNorm_1/beta:0' shape=(512,) dtype=float32_ref>
actor/LayerNorm_1/gamma:0:  <tf.Variable 'actor/LayerNorm_1/gamma:0' shape=(512,) dtype=float32_ref>
actor/dense_2/kernel:0: <tf.Variable 'actor/dense_2/kernel:0' shape=(512, 10) dtype=float32_ref>
actor/dense_2/bias:0:   <tf.Variable 'actor/dense_2/bias:0' shape=(10,) dtype=float32_ref>
```

I tried saving it

```
x = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope='actor/dense/kernel:0')[0]
y = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope='actor/dense_2/bias:0')[0]
tf.saved_model.simple_save(sess, model_save_name, inputs={"state": x}, outputs={"action": y})
```

and then loading it with

```
predict_fn = predictor.from_saved_model(load_dir)
predictions = predict_fn({"state": np.zeros(270)})
```

but I get the error

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (270,) for Tensor 'actor/dense/kernel:0', which has shape '(270, 512)'
```

**I haven't defined a placeholder for the input data. Does this mean I cannot save and then load it via the `simple_save` approach?**

Comment: What version of TensorFlow are you using? 1.x or 2.0 beta?

Comment: TensorFlow version 1.13.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm mistaken, that's not how you use a model in `TensorFlow`.

- First, you need to build your model: this includes the type and shapes of each layer, but also the input layer (placeholder)
- Then, you can train / predict by feeding the placeholder.

In your example, I feel like you would rebuild the model each time you're calling it.

But I think your error comes from `predictions = predict_fn({"state": np.zeros(270)})`. You're feeding a numpy array to your model, but your model does not have a placeholder to put the data in.

Comment: The model works fine and I load and save it via the ```tf.train.Saver()``` but I need to keep track of a bunch of other parameters manually, hence why I wanted to use this method to deploy. So I need to modify the graph to contain a placeholder for the input data